# Why is my new SSD so much slower than my C: drive

Tags: ssd, sata

I just swapped my D: drive (which was a HDD) for a SSD and while it's definitely faster (writes average around 480 MB/s and reads 530 MB/s) it's so much slower than my C: drive which is also an SSD (writes average around 2 GB/s and reads 3.19 GB/s). They're both SATA drives. Not sure what brand the C: drive is (it came with my Lenovo), but the new drive is a Crucial MX500 1TB drive. Is there a way to get the new drive to perform as well as C: or is the connection just different and this is as good as it's going to get?

Comment: Your quoted values for the internal SSD are unreal and the internal one is probably NVME, not SATA.

Comment: Crucial MX500 is a SATA SSD and the speeds you are getting are as expected and within the specifications of a SATA SSD

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm guessing NVME uses a different connection to the motherboard/harness so there's no way that I can add another NVME drive. Is that correct?

Comment: It typically uses a M.2 connector. Laptops usually have only one slot indeed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto this is a desktop. Does that change anything?